# What is this scripting language? <%if $(httpd.requestMethod='POST') >

Tags: http, scripting, busybox

I was browsing throught a small linux distro (based on Busybox - used to run GSM phone switch), and I found many scripts written in the scriptiing-language being included from `xml` files. These files have the extension `csp`

```
<%output disable>
<%if $(httpd.requestMethod='POST') >
  <%call httpd.authenticate: "Please Login">
  <%if $(httpd.authUser='admin') >
    <%if $(httpd.authPassword!=ADMIN_PASSWORD)>
         <%call httpd.forceAuthenticate: "Please Login">
    <%endif>
  <%else>
     <%call httpd.forceAuthenticate: "Please Login">
  <%endif>
  <%if $(param1='1')>
     <%set PROGRAM_ARG_1:=$(param2)>
     <%call syscfg.save>
     <%call system.exec: /usr/bin/echocmd, $(action)>
    <%endif>
  <%endif>
<%endif>
```

It seems like a mix betweem ASP, python and shell scripting!

What is this scripting language? And where can I find its manual?

For example:

I have `send_status.html`, which recieves ajax requests. In this file there is this line `<%include send_status.csp>`. *Magically* this command line `/usr/bin/echocmd, $(action)` is executed! (NOTE: $(action) is expanded to the POST parameter named action - which is terribly bad!).

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's Caché and Caché Server Pages (CSP)

Comment: I checked [CSP Mark-Up language](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20131/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=TCSP_Tags). But it seems not the same syntax. CSP syntax is `<csp:include>` not `<%include>`